# How to create a v-for without v-bind in a component

Tags: php, vue.js, vue-component, v-for, scandir

So I am using php as my backend and Vue as my front. I am currently reading mock folders in my php by using scandir(). I get back a JSON object and am able to retrieve that on my front-end in a Vue component. However, I have not successfully been able to loop through this object in Vue.

Here's my php that reads just the items in the array that are folders:

```
    $campaigns = "./";
    $scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($campaigns), array('..', '.', 'scandir.php', 
    '.DS_Store'));
    print_r(json_encode($scanned_directory));
```

Which gives me:

{"3":"191127_ad_review","4":"191216_new_year","5":"191216_winter_sale"}

Here's my vue component that mounts the info:

```
    mounted() {
    this.getCampaigns()
    },
    methods: {
    getCampaigns() {
        this.axios.get('http://localhost/AdReviewBack/clients/clientABC/scandir.php')

        .then(response => {
            this.campaigns = response.data
            console.log(this.campaigns)
            }
        )

    }
    }
```

In my console log I show this:

```
    {__ob__: Observer}
    3: "191127_ad_review"
    4: "191216_new_year"
    5: "191216_winter_sale"
    __ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
    get 3: ƒ reactiveGetter()
    set 3: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
    get 4: ƒ reactiveGetter()
    set 4: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
    get 5: ƒ reactiveGetter()
    set 5: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
    __proto__: Object
```

I can render {{ this.campaigns }} to show the same response from my php like this:

{ "3": "191127_ad_review", "4": "191216_new_year", "5": "191216_winter_sale" }

My problem is that I don't know what I would use as my v-bind:key. Is it the numbers 3, 4, 5? If so, how would I bind something that is dynamic? Is there a way to use v-for without using v-bind:key? My version of Vue is not allowing it.

I'd like my v-for to work like this:

```
    <li v-for="campaign in campaigns">
        {{ this.campaign }}
```

But that does not work without bind and adding any key that I've tried (index, id, campaign), I get the error "campaign is undefined" even when I have added it as an empty string in my data.

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I missed this for litterally 5 hours! After writing out this whole question I found the problem as soon as I submitted the question.

```
    {{ campaign }}
```

NOT: {{ this.campaign }}

Hope my mistake helps someone else!